# Is there a way to bypass maxpodrange check for a Node during deployment?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

We have an use case where we run pods with hostNetwork set to true, and these pods will be deployed in a dedicated node pool where maxPodRange is set to 32. To avoid IP wastage we are trying to understand if there is a way to override this maxPodRange constraint, so that the kube-scheduler will not restrict us with 32 pods during deployment. Please let me know if you have come across any solution or workaround. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, max pods per node and the size of the CIDR allocated to each node are directly linked and there is no way to separate them.

Given you are planning to use host networking, then it does not really matter which CIDR range GKE assigns to the nodes in this pool.  One option may be to pick add a [random PUPI (privately used public IPv4) range](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/archive/configuring-privately-used-public-ips-for-GKE) to your VPC and then assign that to the specific node pool (when you create a node pool you can assign a specific range).  In this way, you would not waste any of the routable VPC subnets on nodes that will never assign IPs to pods.

Another option would be to pick a non-RFC 1918 range and potentially use it (unless you are already doing that).  For example, you could add something from the class E `240.0.0.0/4` range.

Answer (score 2):

For autopilot cluster 32 is the max and this restriction cannot be bypass. You can use up to 256 IPs for non-autopilot cluster. Checkout the limits [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/quotas#limits_per_cluster) and how to configure [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/flexible-pod-cidr#setting_the_maximum_number_of_pods_in_a_new_node_pool_for_an_existing_cluster).